# Yii: use STAT relation as parameter for another relation's condition

Tags: yii, entity-relationship

Is possible in Yii 1.1.14 use a STAT relation as parameter in the condition of another relation of the same model??

```
public function relations()
{
   return array(
      'attivita' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Attivita', 'attivita_id'),
      'totLezioni'=>array(self::STAT, 'LezioniSettimanali', 'corso_id'),
      'tariffe'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Tariffe',array('id'=>'attivita_id'),'through'=>'attivita','condition' => 'tariffe.tipo=:tc OR tariffe.freqSettimanale = :totLezioni','params' => array(':tc'=>'I',':totLezioni'=>$this->totLezioni)),
   );
}
```

Error: "Corsi"."totLezioni" not defined.

Comment: where the error is show?

Comment: The Error refer to Corsi.totLezioni show the part of code you use this value (controller I presume and view)

Comment: I have this error also if I don't call the relation "tariffe" in my views (it looks as an application error). @scaisEdge The relation 'totLezioni' works fine if I delete "tariffe" relation.

Comment: And $this->totLezioni where is defined /calculated? in which model?

Comment: It's the name of the second relation